# Excel advanced formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The below image show what I want to achieve:

[image]

Explanation:

I have a table mixed with text without format, and bold+italic text. I want to change the format of the bold+italic text to become bold text with orange highlight. The text without format is remain unchanged.

Except format it one by one manually, is there any easier, quicker way to format it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved using VBA. This code is tested in Excel 2013. Though you have not mentioned the version, this should be generic enough to work in Excel 2003 also just in case.

In your worksheet press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open VBA Editor. From **Insert** menu, insert a **Module**. Double click on the inserted module in left pane to open its code editor.

Now paste the following code into it.

```vb
Public Sub myformat()

  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Range("Sheet1!D4:D11")  'Specify the desired SheetName!Range here
  For Each cel In rng.Cells
    If cel.Font.Bold = True And cel.Font.Italic = True Then
        cel.Font.Italic = False
        cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 44  '44 is the color index number for standard Orange in Excel
    End If   
  Next cel

End Sub
```

This creates a VBA Macro named `myformat`.  Here you need to manually specify the SheetName!Range. In this example `Sheet1!D4:D11` is the range of data. 
Save and exit back to worksheet.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to access Macro dialog box and run this `myformat` macro to get the desired effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Format one of the cell to the required format (bold+orange fill)
2. Select that cell, and **double-click** Format Painter
   [image: Format Painter]
3. Select cells you want to format. You can manually clicking them one by one, or dragging if it is a contiguous range.